# Grab template form input in Vue 3 class components (like done in Angular)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I started vue 3 today, and opted for the class-based approach in the cli. I'm from the Angular background, so forgive me for thinking like Angular. Every example I see (even in the docs) is still using the `Vue({...})` thing, however, I wanna do something like this (still thinking Angular-ish)

In angular, I can do this

```html
<form #formData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData.value)">
  <input (ngModel)="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
</form>
```

Then in component

```
...
export class AppComponent {

   public name!: string;

   onSubmit(formData: string) {
      console.log(formData)
   }
}
```

What would be the vue 3 class components approach like the above?

I currently have this in vue 3

```
export default class Welcome extends Vue {
  name!: string;

  onSubmit(formData: any) {
    console.log(formData)
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name="name" v-model="name"/>
      </p>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

What changes do I need to do to the above to connect the form in template to the component?

Answer (score 1):

Without a third party library there isn't the same type of functionality that angular provides. Angular is doing a bunch of additional things to enhance the form object for validation and value tracking, and Vue natively does not do that. However you could instead put your data properties in an object to group them together. That way when you need to access them in something like the submit event to perhaps send all the values to an API, you can simply refer to that object instead of having to handle/build each property separately:

Class:

```
export class AppComponent {
   // create object with bound form properties
   public values: { name: string; } = { name: '' };

   onSubmit() {
      console.log(this.values); // { name: '' }
      // axios.post('/api', this.values).then(res => console.log(res.data));
   }
}
```

Template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name="name" v-model="values.name"/>
      </p>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

That being said, if you do need advanced form features like validation, sanitization, and similar there are plenty of libraries that do it well.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The native [`FormData` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) takes a `<form>` element, which creates the values of the form for all named inputs (`<input>`s or `<textarea>`s with `name` attribute).

So you could update your `onSubmit` method to retrieve the form data values:

```js
export default class Welcome extends Vue {
  name!: string;

  onSubmit(formData: any) {
    const form = e.target
    const formData = new FormData(form)
  }
}
```

*Example using the Options API:*

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" name="name" v-model="name"/>
      </p>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
      const form = e.target
      const formData = new FormData(form)
      console.log({ formData: Array.from(formData.entries()) })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-form-data?file=src/components/MyForm.vue)